# How to draw a pgfplot (Line chart) with text in x-axis instead of number?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am trying to create a Line chart with text at X-axis instead of number but unable to do so. Below is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=0, xmax=30,
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        xtick={10,20,30},
        ytick={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100}
        ]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
        (0,10)
        (8,30)
        (16,40)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Case 1}

    \addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
        plot coordinates {
            (4,15)
            (10,25)
            (15,40)
            (18,60)
        };
    \addlegendentry{Case 2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code generates the following image. I want to be able to use text lets say A,B,C at X axis instead of 10,20,30. Kindly help.
[image: Line chart]

Comment: http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/fill-between-plots/

Comment: After `xtick={10,20,30},` add line `xticklabels={A,B,X},`

Comment: @Zarko Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=0, xmax=30,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    xtick={10,20,30},
    xticklabels={A,B,X},   % <---
    ytick={0,10,...,100}
            ]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (0,10)
    (8,30)
    (16,40)
};
\addlegendentry{Case 1}

\addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
    plot coordinates {
        (4,15)
        (10,25)
        (15,40)
        (18,60)
    };
\addlegendentry{Case 2}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]